# Map a column name with a list value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My df:

```
  Column_Name                            Values
0           X                           [1,2,3]
1           Y                           [a,b,c]
2           Z  [20-09-2020,20-12-2202,1-1-2001]
3           W                     [0.1,0.2,0.3]

# df.dtypes

Values         object
column_name    object
dtype: object
```

How i can create a new dataframe that would look like this where each value of the Column name would be a new column, like this:

```
   X  Y           Z    W
0  1  a  20-09-2020  0.1
1  2  b  20-12-2202  0.2
2  3  c    1-1-2001  0.3
```

Note i have already transposed the table:

```
df_all = pd.read_sql_table('Test',engine)
df_test = pd.Series({c:df_all[c].unique() for c in df_all})
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name': df_test.index,'Values':df_test.values})
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.tolist` and create a new dataframe having the data from column `Values` and index as `Column_Name` then use `DataFrame.T`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['Values'].tolist(), index=df['Column_Name'].tolist()).T
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
   X  Y           Z    W
0  1  a  20-09-2020  0.1
1  2  b  20-12-2202  0.2
2  3  c    1-1-2001  0.3
```

Comment: Salute for the answer!!